# Inequality proof using real numbers

Tags: inequality

If $x,y,z,w$ are positive real numbers such that $x < y$ and $z < w$, show that $xz < yw$. Show the converse and prove it or provide a counterexample.

So I know that the proof is true, I just have no idea how to prove it. It feels like its a fact to me. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Note the converse isn't true.  A counter is: $2\cdot 2 < 1\cdot 5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$ xz - yw = x \cdot \left( z - w \right) + w \cdot \left( x - y \right). $$Since $x-y<0$ and $z-w<0$, we have $ xz - yw < 0 $, so $ xz < yw $. $\Box$

Comment: @ZoëSoriano Does this answer your question?

Comment: You're welcome; thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use the following 
$$xz-yw=x(z-w)+w(x-y)$$

or $$xz-yw=z(x-y)+y(z-w)$$

Answer (score 1):

$x<y \implies \dfrac{x}{y}<1$

$z<w \implies \dfrac{z}{w}<1$

$\therefore \dfrac{xz}{yw}<1$

For this I have used the following lemma.

> **Lemma**
>
> $a<1, b<1 \implies ab<1$
>
> **Proof**
>
> $a<1 \implies \exists \varepsilon_1>0:a=1-\varepsilon_1$
>
> $b<1\implies \exists \varepsilon_2>0:b=1-\varepsilon_2$
>
> $ab=\left(1-\varepsilon_1\right)\left(1-\varepsilon_2\right)=1-\left(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2\right)+\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2$
>
> $$\boxed{\left(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2\right)>\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2 \impliedby \varepsilon_1>\varepsilon_2\left(\varepsilon_1-1\right) \impliedby 
> \varepsilon_1>0}$$